# Get all fields names in a mongodb collection?

Tags: mongodb

I'm coding a mongoose schema so I need a list of possible field in my collection.
Please how can I display all fields names in a specific collection, thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

switch to the db you're using and type:

```
mr = db.runCommand({
  "mapreduce" : "myCollectionName",
  "map" : function() {
    for (var key in this) { emit(key, null); }
  },
  "reduce" : function(key, stuff) { return null; },
  "out": "myCollectionName" + "_keys"
})
```

once you get result, type:

```
db[mr.result].distinct("_id")
```

and you will get a list of fields names.

Comment: You also can add "query" param.
And talking about Robo 3T - you can type both command at same time - it will show results for both commands separated.

Comment: Is there any way to make the solution in this answer "recursive"? That means: also getting all nested field names.