# How to get ALL field names in a MongoDB collection including nested field names using mongo shell?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nosql, schema

I was searching a way to retrieve all possible fields in a MongoDB collection given the fact that in the totality of all documents, not every single one has the same fields in an attempt to be prepared for all possible cases in the task I got at hand.

I found [this useful question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808179/get-all-fields-names-in-a-mongodb-collection/23808256#23808256) to be able to retrieve all fields. The answer is useful but as stated in a comment there, is also possible to get all nested field names too? This question alone requires another question thus, I'd like to know how to do it.

Here's what I mean:

```
total: 15861
ref_code: "0FMjZj"
settings: Object
    pa_rejected: "1"
    pa_redeem: "1"
    new: "1"
```

In this simplified example, using Mongo CLI with the solution shared in the quoted answer I get:

```
[
   "total",
   "ref_code",
   "settings"
]
```

Is there a way to also get `pa_rejected`, `pa_redeem` and `new` somehow?

Comment: Here is a post with some answers which use other tools, but not `mongo` shell: [Mongo Schema Diagram or Report](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongo-schema-diagram-or-report/409)

Answer (score 1):

Apply the map function recursively to the document:

```
db['foo'].deleteMany({})
db['foo'].insert({a:{foo:{bar:{zoom:42}}},b:'c',d:'e',x:[]})

mr = db.runCommand({
  "mapreduce" : "foo",
  "map" : function() {
    var f = function() {
      for (var key in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          emit(key, null)
          if (typeof this[key] == 'object') {
            f.call(this[key])
          }
        }
      }
    }
    f.call(this);
  },
  "reduce" : function(key, stuff) { return null; },
  "out": "myCollectionName" + "_keys"
})


print(db[mr.result].distinct("_id"))
```

Comment: Can you please explain a little about your code here? To be able to understand it better. Thanks again!

Comment: My real problem is the misunderstanding of those concepts (MapReduce, map, reduce, out...) Surely I need an extensive reading of the docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/

Other than that, I don't get clarity about the difference between `foo` (an example collection?) and `myCollectionName` in out...

Comment: Also, I got the following error in Mongo Shell: `E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: keyword 'if' : @(shell):1:204`

Comment: Adding `;` after `emit(key, null)` I got the following: `"errmsg" : "InternalError: too much recursion :\nf@:4:13\nf@:7:13(...)` Still unclear, sorry. Please help with some more advice. Thanks

Comment: Type it exactly as I posted it in mongo shell.