# Get the document having most number of fields in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, migration

I'm trying to create C# models from a huge existing MongoDB database.
Sometimes there are additional fields in specific documents.
I need to get the one with the most number of fields so I can create a C# model that includes all possible fields.

Any other solution to the problem is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all fields names in a mongodb collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808179/get-all-fields-names-in-a-mongodb-collection)

Comment: @D.SM It returns all the fields but it removes the JSON structure.
I need _id of the document to be able to load whole the fields and values.

Comment: Now I lost you. If you want to operate on individual documents, do  a regular find.

Comment: @D.SM It's like I want to select * from MyCollection where _id=(_id of the document having the most number of fields)

Comment: Use the referenced solution to obtain all possible fields then construct a query with $exists:true for every field.