# How can i scan every document in a collection using a regular expression?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection that has many documents that consist of mainly strings but also have some arrays.

example:
field1: 'string'
field2: 'string'
field3: 'array'
etc.

I would like to search through and find all the documents with any occurrence of a 'keyword'.

I tried a regex but dont know how to have it run on every field of each document.

I did: `Model.find({field1: {$regex: ${keyword}, $options: 'mi'}})` and that worked for that field. So  i then tried to create a filter to pass into find(), like this:

`const filter = {field1: {$regex: ${keyword}, $options: 'mi'}, field2: {$regex: ${keyword}, $options: 'mi'}, field3: {$regex: ${keyword}, $options: 'mi'},etc.}`

Which i then passed like this: `Model.find(filter)` But this does not work.

Comment: Combine those field regex clauses with `$or`

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank You. Can you submit it as an answer so that i can mark it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combine those invididual field clauses with an `$or`. Something like this:

```
const filter = {"$or": [
                 {field1: {$regex: ${keyword}, $options: 'mi'}, 
                 {field2: {$regex: ${keyword}, $options: 'mi'},
               ]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with map/reduce.

See [Get all fields names in a mongodb collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808179/get-all-fields-names-in-a-mongodb-collection) for how to identify all fields in a document. Add your own conditions on each of the fields as needed.